# Contraining a number of assets to be less than or equal to using cvxpy

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I am trying to use cvxpy to minimize the tracking error, defined as the standard deviation of the portfolio return minus the index return, with a few constraints including

1. the sum of weights of all assets chosen has to equal to 100%
2. the weight of each asset should be >=3% and <=20%
3. the total number of assets chosen should be less than or equal to 12

Right now, I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import os

os.chdir(r'\\Directory')
input_file # 48 x 17
base_weights # 17 x 1

msci_na = input_file['MSCI North America Index'] # 17 x 1
funds = input_file.loc[:, input_file.columns != 'MSCI North America Index'] # 48 X 17
funds_np = funds.to_numpy()

# Generate random data for demonstration
n_funds = len(funds.columns)
weights = cp.Variable(n_funds)

# Define the tracking error objective function
tracking_error = cp.norm(funds_np @ weights - msci_na, 2) / np.sqrt(47)

# Define the constraints
constraints = [cp.sum(weights) == 1, weights >= 0.03, weights <= 0.20]

# Define the problem and solve
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(tracking_error), constraints)
problem.solve()

# Retrieve the optimal weights
optimal_weights = weights.value
```

the input_file has 48 months of returns for 17 assets along with the index. The goal is to choose at most 12 out of these 17 assets to minimize the tracking error of the resulting portfolio relative to the index return. I am having difficulty adding the contraint (as you can see, I already added the first two constraints). I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: This is called a cardinality constrained portfolio problem. Warning: you need an MIQP solver for that.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Do you know which library does that?

Comment: e.g. Cplex, Gurobi, Xpress, Mosek, SCIP, . . .